# проблема с парсингом номера телефона на сайте avito

Tags: php, javascript, парсер, phpquery

Делаю парсер объявлений с avito. Возникла проблема парсинга номера телефона. Расклад следующий: после нажатия на кнопку "позвонить" avito оправляет get запрос такого типа:

https://m.avito.ru/voronezh/predlozheniya_uslug/elektrik_1178716261/phone/f7ec08892c776860c093194f95f59e3e?async&searchHash=jyoxq52w9wgg8wssss08ww44c8g0swc

где searchHash это уникальный "ключ"запроса. Как я понял он генерируется через js скрипт. Вопрос в следующем: как при парсинге спарсить js переменную с searchHash  значением? Для парсинга использую phpQuery. Так же хотел спросить есть ли другие способы узнать значение searchHash? Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Avito по этой причине и хеширует и телефон и весь запрос в целом, что бы к нему не кто не добрался. Сгенерировать такой хеш вы не сможете, так как вам не известна кодировка